# количество замен в последовательности чисел

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Нужно посчитать количество замен в задаваемой последовательности чисел. Долго мучилась, но все попытки оказались неудачными :(

```py
from numpy import *

n = int(input('Введите размер массива: '))
N = zeros(n,dtype='int')

for i in range(n):
    print('Введите N[', i ,']: ', end='')
    N[i] = int(input())
    print('Введенный массив: ', N)

z = int(input('Введите число z: '))
         
for index, item in enumerate(N):
    if item < z:
        N[index] = round(z)

print(N)
```

Comment: Ну заведите переменную-счётчик и увеличивайте её при каждой замене

Comment: np.sum(N<z) - подсчет, N[N<z]=z  - замена. Все.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Вроде работает
from numpy import *

n = int(input('Введите размер массива: '))
N = zeros(n,dtype='int')

for i in range(n):
    print('Введите N[', i ,']: ', end='')
    N[i] = int(input())
    print('Введенный массив: ', N)
k = 0
z = int(input('Введите заменяющее: '))
x = int(input('Введите заменяемое: '))
for index, item in enumerate(N):
    if  item == x:
        k+=1
        N[index] = round(z)
print(N,k)
```